# How to validate characters, numbers and special characters using jQuery regular expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate password field such that it accepts characters, numbers and also special characters. **It must accept exactly 8 characters**. I have searched for it in the internet but I was not able to get any specific answer and if getting its not working.

Let me just give an explanation of the characters the password must accept:
**A-Z, a-z, 0-9, ~!@#$%^&*()_-+=.|<>?{}[]**

So, valid password would be: `ankit@19`, `a_g-1#87`, etc.
Invalid password would be: `ag/ i(91` (because it is having space and '`/`' in it)

The regular expression I am using right now is:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9?=\.~!@#\$%^&*()_-|<>{}\[\]]{8}$/
```

This one is not working at all. Please help me to get the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[A-Za-z0-9?=.~!@#\$%^&*()_|<>{}\[\]-]{8}$
```

You need to take `-` at the end and escape `[]` inside `[]`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mG8kZ9/13

Comment: The square brackets are already escaped (issues with post formatting), but the hyphen indeed was not.

Comment: do I need to escape "-" like "\-" also? @stribizhev

Comment: Only in the middle of the character class. No need escaping it at the beginning and end of the character class, or after a range or when a shorthand class is adjacent to the hyphen.

Comment: @Agnib no you dont if it is at end...if it is in middle yes

Comment: @vks - Thanks a lot for giving an idea about regex101.com. Secondly, I looked into that demo and found that at the end of the pattern they are also using 'gm' and then only its matching. Why so? Please can you explain. Thirdly, the matching strings are getting highlighted. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev and vks

Comment: @vks - The matching strings will get highlighted by blue / sky blue color, isn't it? If yes, then when I am removing 'm', its not getting highlighted

Comment: @Agnib that is because the input here is multiline....just give one line and remove `m`

Comment: @vks - yeah, I did that also. But, still I saw that unless I am using 'm', its not working.

Comment: @vks - Ok. But, I also did that - https://regex101.com/r/mG8kZ9/13. Its not working here. Do I need to refresh or add new solution etc.?

Comment: @Agnib update the link and post it...you have posted an old link.make sure you dont have a `newline` after input

Comment: @vks - Ok. Thanks a lot dude :)

Comment: @vks - I need your help again... I am using that regular expression and then matching it with input value but its not working in jquery. For Example: var pwd_pattern = /^[A-Za-z0-9?=.~!@#\$%^&*()_|{}\[\]-]{8}$/g       var password = "123456@w" and then if (!pwd_pattern.test($.trim(user.password))) { alert('error'); }. After running, its showing error but the input value matches with the expression. Please help

Comment: @Agnib not so much into js...just regex :P

Comment: @vks - Did not understand